# [Flutter]: Error: Build failed after adding any of these libraries like location & appsflyer

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My app working fine. Now i want to add appsflyer and location sdk in my project. After adding appsflyer_sdk: ^6.13.0+2 package, my build failed continuously.

If i removed these packages from my pubspec.yaml file, app works fine.

Below are the screenshots of my pubspec.yaml file and errors:

[pubspec.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REOeq.png)

**Errors**

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXuYG.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGavJ.png)

**Tried**

Upgraded ext.kotlin_version = '' version as described in error logs, but still getting same error.

**Expectations**

- How can i resolve this?
- Want to know the root cause of this issue because it might be possible that there may be some other issue will be raised in future related with this issue.

Comment: have you tried changing the ext.kotlin_version in build.gradle file?

Comment: @MunsifAli Yes, I mentioned this in my Tried steps.

Comment: Bcz u r using updated version of 3rd party packages. 1. u can solve it by downgrading ur appsflyer_sdk package version (https://pub.dev/packages/appsflyer_sdk/versions). 2. if wanna have updated packages then update ur gradle, kotlin version.

Comment: @JBJason Nothing related with 3rd party packages. I shared my small change which resolved this issue. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

After updating flutter version, this issue raised. I did many changes as suggested on stackoverflow related to this issue but nothing works for me.

Finally, i got solution of this issue and going to shared here for others.

There is no big change needed for this, log message mislead to upgrade ext.kotlin_version = ''.

Simply need to upgrade

> org.jetbrains.kotlin.android

version

In my case, i updated it from 1.7.10 to 1.9.0

Below is the screenshot for reference

[settings.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4taqi.png)